# UWP ToggleButton PointerOver and Checked collision

Tags: uwp

After toggle button is pressed and becomes checked, it's still showing the visual state of `PointerOver` instead of `Checked`, until I move aside the pointer. How can I make the toggle button show the state of `Checked` immediately after clicking even with `PointerOver` it?

[image]

This is the code for my toggle button:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MediaControlToggleButtonTemplate" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <ContentPresenter
            x:Name="ContentPresenter"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
            Background="Transparent"
            BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
            ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
            CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
            FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MediaControlToggleButtonPointerOverBackgroundBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MediaControlToggleButtonPointerOverBorderBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MediaControlToggleButtonPressedBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MediaControlToggleButtonPressedBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MediaControlToggleButtonPressedBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MediaControlToggleButtonCheckedBackgroundBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundChecked}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushChecked}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click ToggleButton, the pointer still stays at ToggleButton. The state is not `Checked`, but `CheckedPointerOver`, and you are missing the VisualState of this state.

You can copy the contents of `Check` VisualState and add it to `CheckedPointerOver` like:

```xml
<VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MediaControlToggleButtonCheckedBackgroundBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundChecked}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushChecked}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

So you can see the effect immediately after the mouse click.

Best regards.